# Native Express Ads are not showing within my UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, admob

My goal is to have Native Express Ad's show up in my UITableView that's using Sections. Every 10th TOTAL cell (combining together the cells from all sections) should be a Native Express Ad. Every other cell will be a normal cell.

The problem is no Ads are ever showing up. I believe the issue lies in my cellForRowAt cast. I followed Andrew Brogdon's tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chNb7-k6m4M - I think the part I'm getting confused at is around the 5:10 mark.

I am casting the objectsArray as AnyObject so that the cells can hold both FruitObjects and GADNativeExpressAdView

My code:

**Class:**

```
struct FruitObjects {
    var sectionName: String!
    var sectionObjects: [FruitModel]!
}
var objectsArray = [AnyObject]()
```

**viewDidLoad:**

```
objectsArray = [
        FruitObjects(sectionName: "A", sectionObjects: [
            FruitModel(fruitTerm: "Apple", definition: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet."),
            FruitModel(fruitTerm: "Apple 2", definition: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet."),
            FruitModel(fruitTerm: "Apple 3", definition: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.")
            ]) as AnyObject,

        FruitObjects(sectionName: "B", sectionObjects: [
            FruitModel(fruitTerm: "Banana", definition: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet."),
            FruitModel(fruitTerm: "Banana 2", definition: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet."),
            FruitModel(fruitTerm: "Banana 3", definition: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.")
            ]) as AnyObject,

        FruitObjects(sectionName: "C", sectionObjects: [
            FruitModel(fruitTerm: "Clementine", definition: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet."),
            FruitModel(fruitTerm: "Clementine 2", definition: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.")
            ]) as AnyObject

]
```

**UITableViewDataSource:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let myCast = objectsArray[section] as? FruitObjects
    return myCast!.sectionObjects.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return objectsArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let myCast = objectsArray[section] as? FruitObjects
    return myCast!.sectionName
}
```

**cellForRowAt:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let myCast = objectsArray[indexPath.section] as? FruitObjects{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = myCast.sectionObjects[indexPath.row].fruitTerm
        print("CELL")
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let adView = objectsArray[indexPath.row] as! GADNativeExpressAdView
        let reusableAdCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NativeExpressAdViewCellReuseID", for: indexPath)
        // MISSING removeFromSuperview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chNb7-k6m4M 5:51
        reusableAdCell.contentView.addSubview(adView)
        adView.center = reusableAdCell.contentView.center
        print("NATIVE")
    }
 }
```

Can you help me get Native Ads showing up every 10th cell?

I believe the issue lies in the code I posted above. Perhaps in my casting? If nothing looks jarringly off, let me know and I will post more of my ViewController.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you're able to provide!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to loading the first Ad in (from the video link you provided)

```
 func nativeExpressAdViewDidReceiveAd(_ nativeExpressAdView: GADNativeExpressAdView) { }
```

Also, the size specified, used.

```
let size = GADAdSizeFullWidthPortraitWithHeight(300)
```

Try to load the request in deque cell, as the ad load happens in cell deque. No worries as we are removing the subviews before we add.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NativeExpressAdViewCellReuseID",for: indexPath)

        let adView = self. objectsArray[indexPath.row] as! GADNativeExpressAdView

        for subView in cell.contentView.subviews {
            subView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.contentView.addSubview(adView)
        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]//for running it in simulator
        adView.load(request)
        adView.center = cell.contentView.center
        return cell
```

}